# Javascript simple onclick image swap

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use Javascript to swap an image, so far I can get it from A to B, but not back.

Here is what I'm using to create one swap:

```
<img src="pic1.png" name="pic" onclick="window.document.pic.src='pic2.png';"/>
```

This swaps image 1 to image 2, simple enough. But I want to be able to revert back to image 1 by clicking on the new image 2. I tried using this:

```
<img src="pic1.png" name="pic" onclick="
if (window.document.pic.src='pic1.png'){
window.document.pic.src='pic2.png';
} 
else if (window.document.pic.src='pic2.png'){
window.document.pic.src='pic1.png';
}"/>
```

It doesn't seem to work in this instance. It will switch to pic2, but not switch back to pic1. Is it something to do with onclick? My if statements? Thanks

Comment: try using 2 if statements instead of an if else if

Comment: Also, i don't know your whole coding scheme but is window necessary? window.document.pic.src?

Comment: using 2 if statements didnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code the problem is
 when you alert window.document.pic.src its print like http://localhost/pic1.png 
 and then you are are use condition if (window.document.pic.src == 'pic1.png')
how is it true.
 try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function test()
{
    alert(window.document.pic.src);
     //alert msg print like http://localhost/test/pic1.png
    if (document.pic.src=='http://localhost/test/pic1.png'){

document.pic.src='pic2.png';
} 
else if (document.pic.src=='http://localhost/test/pic2.png'){

document.pic.src='pic1.png';
}
}
</script>
<img src="pic1.png" name="pic" onclick="test()"/>
```

Answer (score 12):

Try this simple trick... easy to maintain.

```
<script>
var onImg= "on.jpg";
var offImg= "off.jpg";
</script>
<img src="on.jpg" onclick="this.src = this.src == offImg ? onImg : offImg;"/>
```

Comment: It should be noted, that as mentioned above that src returns the whole path. To make this still work you can just modify the onclick function to: "this.src = (this.src.endsWith(offImg)? onImg : offImg);" Very neat solution though!

Comment: This is so far the simplest solution I've seen. But is it possible to tweak it, so a click yet again shows the original image (toggle)?

Answer (score 2):

wrong use of == in if condition

```
if (window.document.pic.src == 'pic1.png'){
window.document.pic.src='pic2.png';
} 
else if (window.document.pic.src =='pic2.png'){
window.document.pic.src='pic1.png';
}"/>
```

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure why but using == didn't work in the single switch either.

Answer (score 1):

1. `window.document.pic.src='pic1.png'` assigns `pic1.png` to the left hand side. It does NOT compare.
2. Though not directly relevant, try not to access elements by their name globally. Use their `id`.
3. Your javascript should not be inside the onclick. It should be inside a javasctipt `function`

Combined:

The img tag:

```
<img src="pic1.png" name="pic" id="pic" onclick="swap()"/>
```

The javascript

```
<script>
function swap()
{
   if (document.getElementById("pic").src.endsWith('pic1.png') != -1)  //==:Comparison
   { 
      document.getElementById("pic").src = "pic2.png"; //=:assignment   
   } 
   else if (window.document.pic.src.endsWith('pic2.png') != -1) 
   { 
      document.getElementById("pic").src = "pic1.png"; 
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi there, I tried your exact code, it didn't work in Chrome or Firefox. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code is doing what the below lines do, it's not going inside an `if else` block, so if you remove your `if else` block the code still will work, because on mouse click it sets the value of `src` as 'pic2.png', which was 'pic1.png' earlier, and when you click again because it's already pic2.png so it remains the same.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function swap() {
    window.document.pic.src='pic2.png';
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<img src="pic1.png" name="pic" onclick="swap()"> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -4):

You can try this.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Swapping Images</title>
</head>
<body>
<img id="myimg" src="img1.jpg" hieght="300" width="300" onClick="change ()"/>
</body>
</html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function change () {
  var img=document.getElementById("myimg");
  if (img.src === "img1")
    img.src="img2.jpg";
  else 
    img.src="img1.jpg";
}
</script>
</head>
</html>
```