# Transition effects with javascript for swapping images using onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website that shows 3 images. Instead of re directing the users to a new page I decided that I want to use the same page.

### Question

How can I make it so when users click a `<button>` 3 new images display in the view, other 3 fades out. Using pure javascript, not jQuery.

Comment: Please show the code (HTML, CSS and JavaScript) that you are working with.

Comment: Welcome to the site. When posting a question make sure that you show your work, show us the code that you have so far.

Comment: This should get you started https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363439/javascript-simple-onclick-image-swap

Answer (score 0):

You could use JavaScript to change the image source. Just add an ID to each image and then:

```
document.getElementById(“yourID”).src = “your new source”;
```